# My Lumix GH4 flash has stopped working — what can I do?

Tags: troubleshooting, panasonic, popup-flash

My Lumix GH4 internal flash has stopped working.  It's not in silent mode, electronic shutter or in HD.  I've tried resetting the camera and now am at wits end.  Any advice?

Comment: Going by the amount of information that you've given us I can only recommend that you bring it to a professional to find out what is wrong as you've effectively said: "my flash broke, what's wrong with it".

Answer (score 6):

You ask for *any* advice, so I'm going to provide that. Your built-in flash seems like it's broken. So, you should *ignore it* and get a shoe-mount flash, since your camera comes with a standard hot shoe. This comes with several advantages, including significantly increased power, and (with most flashes) the ability to bounce the light off of the ceiling instead of pointing straight forward.

Even better, go for one of the new low-cost radio-control systems like Godox. Put the controller in the hotshoe and the flash somewhere where it'll produce better light than you'll ever get with an on-camera flash.

This is easily the most cost-effective way to improve most indoor photography *anyway*, and gives you many more options for creative image-making. Think of this problem as encouragement towards something that's a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have two basic options:

- Send it to a repair center to see if the flash can be fixed.
- Continue using the camera without the internal flash. Since the GH4 has a hot shoe, you can use an external flash instead.

The second option will probably be cheaper (especially if you choose a third party flash, even one that is compatible with Panasonic's flash communication protocol that will allow you to use 'auto' as well as 'manual' flash) than the first, and will almost certainly increase the flash power available to you.